# All backend services are in UNHEALTHY state

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to expose my react application deployed on gcp to the Internet using Ingress but after applying the ingress I'm getting this error on Gke-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mSDZ.png)

Can anybody help me as I'm stuck on this for quite some time

`apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 kind: Ingress metadata: name: report-ingress annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: reportweb-ip labels: app: hello spec: defaultBackend: service: name: report-ui port: number: 8080`

this is the ingress file that I've applied for my service named report-ui and passed my reserved static IP address